# How to convert XML based String value to integer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

Here is the XML code seperated by commas, i am parsing this as a string, now need to convert  as integer: 
struct in .h file:
    NSString * positions;

XML file:
    100,280,924,320

here is the code:

```
 NSArray * positons = [partyMember elementsForName:@"position"];
    if (positons.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [positons objectAtIndex:0];
        //parsed[i].positons = firstName.stringValue;
        parsed[i].positons = firstName.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"position-%@,\n",parsed[i].positons);
```

first name is locally declared , parsed[i].positions has da parsed value,

Comment: what does the nslog print? is it like this `position-100`   `position-280`      `position-924`

Comment: right now it is printing only 1st position i,e 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i did :) change Objectatindex value while applying it in viewcontroller

```
 NSArray * positons = [partyMember elementsForName:@"position"];
    if (positons.count > 0) {
        GDataXMLElement *firstName = (GDataXMLElement *) [positons objectAtIndex:0];
        //parsed[i].positons = firstName.stringValue;
        parsed[i].positons = firstName.stringValue;
        NSLog(@" parsed position is %d, i = %d\n",[parsed[i].positons integerValue],i);
        NSArray* arr = [parsed[i].positons componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
       // firstStr = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        NSLog(@"position-%d,\n",[[arr objectAtIndex:2] intValue]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get an array of strings using:

```
NSArray* arr = [fullStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","]
```

and then get an int from that

```
int firstInt = [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Comment: @daveGot it Thanks a lotttt!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code for getting the integer values from string:

1. First get the comma separated objects in any array like this:

   ```
   NSArray *arrObjects=[parsed[i].positons componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   ```
2. Then by using that array convert string value to integer as below:

   ```
   int iFirstValue=[[arrObjects objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
   ```

similar for others.

Comment: @Dr.Droid: I just improved the formatting of the answer a bit. All praise should go to @svrushal! You can also upvote the answer if you liked it, in addition to accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a NSString to int value by:

```
[string intValue];
[string floatValue];
```

but this make sense only if the the value is number but in string form,